# Why is that $|e^{-x^{2}}-e^{-y^{2}}|\leq K|x-y|$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions

I am currently studying for an exam about differential equations and in one exercise I have to prove that the function $f(t,x)=te^{-x^{2}}$, $|t|\leq 1$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz-continous with respect to the second variable x on the domain $\mathbb{R}$.

My professor has shown that $|e^{-x^{2}}-e^{-y^{2}}|\leq K|x-y|$, but I don't see this result. Can anyone enlighten me, and explain me why is that?

> My professors reasoning, $$|te^{-x^{2}}-te^{-y^{2}}|= |t||e^{-x^{2}}-e^{-y^{2}}| \leq |e^{-x^{2}}-e^{-y^{2}}| \leq K|x-y|\hspace{3mm}\forall |t|\leq 1, x\in \mathbb{R}$$
> Hence $f(t,x)$ is globally Lipschitz-continous with respect to the second variable x on $\mathbb{R}$.

I understand each and every equality/inequality except for the last one.

I have to point out that if I use the mean value theorem, then $K$ depends on $x$, so $K_x$
$$|e^{−x^2}−e^{−y^2}|=∣\frac{−2r}{e^{r^2}}∣|x−y|\leq2r|x−y|$$
with $r\in[x,y]$ so that would mean that my function $f(t,x)$ is locally Lipschitz-continous with respect to $x$. But my professor is saying a stronger thing, he is saying that $f(t,x)$ is globally Lipschitz-continous.

Comment: Don't make that last estimate in your comment above. Instead, just let $K$ be the global maximum of $2r e^{-r^2}$ for $r \in \mathbf{R}$ (it's a bounded function).

Comment: More generally, the mean value theorem asserts that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq c |x - y|$ where $c$ is any upper bound of $|f'(\xi)|$ for $\xi$ between $x$ and $y.$ Therefore, every function with bounded derivative is Lipschitzian everywhere on its domain (e.g. a continuously differentiable function will be Lipschitzian on every bounded interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From L'Hopital's rule:
$$\lim_{r \to \infty}\frac{r}{\exp(r^2)}=\lim_{r \to - \infty}\frac{r}{\exp(r^2)}=0$$
Thus, we may pick $N$ large enough such that $|r|>N$ implies
$$\big| \frac{r}{\exp(r^2)}\big| \leq 1$$
By the Extreme value theorem, since $r \mapsto r/ \exp(r^2)$ is continuous, and $[-N,N]$ is a closed and bounded interval, we know this function attains a maximum and minimum there. In other words, we can pick $M$ large enough such that $|r| \leq N$ implies
$$\big| \frac{r}{\exp(r^2)}\big| \leq M$$
Putting the pieces together, we have that, for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$:$$\big| \frac{r}{\exp(r^2)}\big| \leq \max(1,M)$$
So we can use $K= \max(1,M)$